# PDO only returns half of the results from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

In the following script, I've bound all the parameters using positional offsets to handle the `IN` clause in PDO. `$_POST["group"]` is an array. The Chrome Console shows that there are 12 values in the array in Form Data. The number of question marks in the In Clause also corresponds to that of the values. Everything seems to be set fine.

```
SELECT a.id,a.likes,a.dislikes from `like_dislike` a 
INNER JOIN `model_no` b ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE b.model_no IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

But I have no idea why the script can only return six of the results.

```
0 likes, 0 dislikes
0 likes, 0 dislikes
0 likes, 0 dislikes
0 likes, 0 dislikes
0 likes, 0 dislikes
0 likes, 0 dislikes
```

I've also run the query in phpmyadmin and there's no problem with the query. 
Can anyone see if there's anything wrong during the binding process?

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename", $username, $password);
$id_group = $_POST["group"];
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($id_group) - 1) . '?';    

$sql = "SELECT a.id,a.likes,a.dislikes from `like_dislike` a 
        INNER JOIN `model_no` b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.model_no IN ($in)";

$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$i = 1;
foreach ($id_group as $id) {
  $users->bindValue($i++, $id);
}

$users->execute($id_group);

$rows = $users->fetchAll();


foreach($rows as $row)
{    
 echo "<div id='tid_".$row['id'].">".$row['likes']." likes, ".$row['dislikes']." dislikes</div>";      
}
```

Comment: Did your input/select element in HTML contains name attribute as `name="group[]"` ?

Comment: I use jQuery `load` method, so it shouldn't be a problem. And the console shows that 12 values have been passed

Comment: @Log1cツ "Fell" for your test without the picture... just liked you name.... also +1 for the question

Comment: @RedGiant, I'm not asking about jQuery and all, as in your code I can see you are reading parameter in POST method, so, it would be more helpful if you post that HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got the solution,

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{    
 echo "<div id='tid_".$row['id'].">".$row['likes']." likes, ".$row['dislikes']." dislikes</div>";   
               ^--this quote     ^--you forgot to end here.
}
```

**Fixed code**

I would suggest to use, `{}` while concatenating array/variables with string. It would be more readable and easy to understand.

```
 echo "<div id='tid_{$row['id']}'>{$row['likes']} likes, {$row['dislikes']} dislikes</div>";
```